# Firebase or other database should i choose for an android app storing weekly schedule?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, firebase, couchbase

I have to build an android app where an admin user should upload the weekly schedule of couriers who are the users, and then every user should view their own schedule and not other's courier schedule. Also, the admin user should see all the features of the app while the users should see restricted features. I guess that the admin user can upload an excel file with the schedule via a webmin or a webapp? Obviously, to implement this I need to use a database so my question is which database should I choose? I searched online and I found out that SQLite needs server coding while Firebase and CouchBase do not and I can use JSON to store data. I am not very familiar with databases, that would be the first time I will use one so anyone who has done something similar?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sqlite isn't a server database. Since this is a recommendation question, it's off topic

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using the firebase because its easy to use and provide many functionalities that you don't have to worry to maintain. I find it pretty easy to use and firebase documentation on how to use their product is well presented and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for (a) both remote and on-device local storage options  or (b) just a remote storage option or (c) just local storage option ?

Couchbase is a full stack data platform so it supports all these options. 
That said, Couchbase server isn't hosted so you will need to setup the database server and you will need to write server side code to access it. It isn't hard to do that- there are SDKs for many platforms. 
That said, it depends on what your needs are.

Comment: The admin user will upload a CSV with data and other users should see their schedule which will be part of the CSV data. So that is remote storage and local storage, well local storage can be used to save the schedule in the device and retrieve it faster rather than retrieving it from the database. i have started to look and set up Firebase and so far looks good.